# How do I spread my RU/s across multiple regions in CosmosDB (python)?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm using PyMongo to insert Documents into CosmosDB in the following way:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db_entry = {"id": 1, "partitionKey": 5}
cdb_client = MongoClient(COSMO_URI).events.face_events_unlimited
cdb_client.insert_one(db_entry)
```

My Azure portal Metrics page looks like this:
[image: Portal Metrics]

One of the regions lists 2.02 kRU/s, the other lists 0 RU/s

How do I start using the other Region?

I have 3000 RU/s provisioned in 2 regions... Does this mean I should be able to put 3000 in each region, or is there a total of 3000 RU/s?

How do I separate my inserts so that they are evenly spread across 2 regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.How do I start using the other Region?

[image]

[image]

> 2.I have 3000 RU/s provisioned in 2 regions... Does this mean I should be able to put 3000 in each region, or is there a total of 3000 RU/s?

***If you provision 'R' RUs on a Cosmos container (or database), Cosmos DB ensures that 'R' RUs are available in each region associated with your Cosmos account. Each time you add a new region to your account, Cosmos DB automatically provisions 'R' RUs in the newly added region. The operations performed against your Cosmos container are guaranteed to get 'R' RUs in each region.***

You could view the statements from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scaling-throughput#how-provisioned-throughput-is-distributed-across-regions).

3.How do I separate my inserts so that they are evenly spread across 2 regions?

I think it's auto provisioned if you set multi-write region. You also could see the official statements in above link:

***You can't selectively assign RUs to a specific region. The RUs provisioned on a Cosmos container (or database) are provisioned in all the regions associated with your Cosmos account.***

Comment: what you are referring to is the RU distribution. not how the writes are done

Answer (score 1):

You can construct 2 different clients (one for each region, assuming you have 2 regions only). .NET sdk allow to specify the region you are using, not sure about python sdk

as for the second question - means you have 3000 RU/s in each region, because each region increases the cost by 100%, so 1 region costs x, 2 regions cost 2x, 3 regions cost 3x